# current location works perfect with long and lat null values, however not with IOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I want to get my current location on a map on IOS, however long: null and lat: null, both seem to get the current location on a map for android but do not work for IOS, what do I do to get the current location on IOS ? below is the code, for example my initial region is lat:null, and long: null, however on android i get the current location, however on ios i do not

```
  class MapScreen extends Component {
  //Set the HeaderTitle screen
  static navigationOptions = props => {
    const placeName = props.navigation.getParam("placeName");
    return { headerTitle: placeName.toUpperCase() };
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Initial State
    this.state = {
      lat: null,
      long: null,
      places: [],
      isLoading: false,
      placeType: "restaurant"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const placeType = navigation.getParam("placeType");
    this.setState({ placeType: placeType });

    this.getCurrentLocation();
  }

/**
   * Get current user's position
   */
  getCurrentLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const long = position.coords.longitude;
      this.setState({ lat: lat, long: long });
      this.getPlaces();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get the Place URL
   */
  getPlacesUrl(lat, long, radius, type, apiKey) {
    const baseUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?`;
    const location = `location=${lat},${long}&radius=${radius}`;
    const typeData = `&types=${type}`;
    const api = `&key=${apiKey}`;
    return `${baseUrl}${location}${typeData}${api}`;
  }

  getPlaces() {
    const { lat, long, placeType } = this.state;
    const markers = [];
    const url = this.getPlacesUrl(lat, long, 1500, placeType, GOOGLE_API_KEY);
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        res.results.map((element, index) => {
          const marketObj = {};
          marketObj.id = element.id;
          marketObj.name = element.name;
          marketObj.photos = element.photos;
          marketObj.rating = element.rating;
          marketObj.vicinity = element.vicinity;
          marketObj.marker = {
            latitude: element.geometry.location.lat,
            longitude: element.geometry.location.lng
          };

          markers.push(marketObj);
        });
        //update our places array
        this.setState({ places: markers });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { lat, long, places } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.mapView}>
          <MapView
            style={{
              flex: 1
            }}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: lat,
              longitude: long,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421
            }}
          >
            {places.map((marker, i) => (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={i}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: marker.marker.latitude,
                  longitude: marker.marker.longitude
                }}
                title={marker.name}
              />
            ))}
          </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried [**react-native-geolocation-service**](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

```
React native geolocation service for iOS and android.
```

### Why ?

This library is created in an attempt to fix the location timeout issue on android with the react-native's current implementation of Geolocation API. This library tries to solve the issue by using Google Play Service's new FusedLocationProviderClient API, which Google strongly recommends over android's default framework location API. It automatically decides which provider to use based on your request configuration and also prompts you to change the location mode if it doesn't satisfy your current request configuration.

NOTE: Location request can still timeout since many android devices have GPS issue in the hardware level or in the system software level. Check the FAQ for more details.

Comment: No the problems isn't with Android, the current location works perfectly fine when loading the map, the problem is the map doesn't load at the current location for IOS

Comment: first, you should update your geolocation function to use, https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation
as the react community recommended.


second, try to set options for the geolocation.getCurrentPosition
options is an object with => {
timeout: number of miliseconds,
maximumAge: number of miliseconds,
enableHighAccuracy: boolean,
}
* try to set enableHighAccuracy: false

Comment: thanks ! turns out just needed import geolocation and a boolean"ready: false" in the initial state, then {this.state.ready && ( <MapView,